# "The childrens' blankets" or "The children's blankets"

Tags: grammar, possessives

I know that when we're talking about something that is possessed collectively by all children it is "children's". What about a scenario where one of the possessed nouns belongs to each individual child?

Comment: I think it's General Reference that *childrens* isn't a word in the first place, so it can't take a "possessive apostrophe".

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/614821/2085).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, *childrens* isn't a word, so it's still *children's*.  Just one more ambiguity in the English language.

Comment: Where's the ambiguity? In the men's (or women's) room?

Comment: @Robusto 'Children' is the plural of 'child'. So 'childrens' makes no sense.

Comment: @Robusto like the OP said, does "children's blankets" mean each child has a blanket or the children share some blankets? *Men's room* is clear, there's one room that belongs to (in this case is used by) multiple men. The equivalent to this question would be *men's rooms*, do the men own rooms individually or collectively? Though thinking about it, even normal plural possessives don't really make that distinction.

Comment: To denote that every child had a blanket say: "each child's blanket".

Comment: source for this answer?

Comment: See ['travellers cheques' 'customers requirements': use of the singular Saxon -genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523431/travellers-cheques-customers-requirements-use-of-the-singular-saxon-genitive/523436#523436). 'Working mens clubs' is now so common that _mens_ must be seen as an addition to the lexis. And _childrens_ is arguably there too.